# EclipseLink composite persistence unit class declaration

Tags: java, persistence, eclipselink, composite

Until now I had 3 persistence units in one `persistence.xml` file. But I found out about composite persistence unit and now would like to implement it into my project. Here is an example on doing this using `<jar-file>` tags and separate `persistence.xml` files: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite

Is it possible to have all your entities in one package (not `.jar`) and use `<class>` tags instead of `<jar-file>` like when you have few non composite persistence units in one `persistence.xml` file?  If not, how to export separate persistence units into `.jar` files?

Comment: Did you find out how to use a single persistence.xml with a composite persistence unit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the classes do not need to be in the jars files, only the persistence.xml file.

Comment: It does not work. It does not recognizes any of the entities.

Comment: EclipseLink v2.4.0 works fine for me without <jar-file>, in test and in OSGi

Comment: hey @earcam, do you have and osgi example with composite PU?

Comment: earcam, Can you provide example configuration here as I am also struggling to configure composite PU and its members without persistemce.xml file. Your help will be really helpful to me.